# Removing records in StandardSetController

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardsetcontroller

I have a standardsetcontroller to display some records. I'm adding a row level button to remove the records from the list using a rowIndex variable. I'm getting the collection object in a list and am trying to remove the object.

Here is the function:

```
    //Deletes row
public void deleteRow(){
    List<cust_obj__c> objs = setCon.getRecords();
    cust_obj__c removedObj = objs.get(rowIndex);
    if(delObjs == null) {
        delObjs = new List<cust_obj__c>();
    }

    if (removedObj.id != NULL) {
        delObjs.add(removedObj);
    }
    objs.remove(rowIndex);
}
```

However when I try to do this, it gives an error System.FinalException: Collection is read-only.

I understand that I'm trying to delete a read only collection and would possibly have to clone the records and remove it from the list. But I do not see any methods on StandardSetController which do an update on the records. So even if I do something like this:

```
    cloned_objs = setCon.getRecords().deepClone(true, true, true);
```

How do I refresh my list on the VF page and how do I save the cloned objs back. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can remove records from the selected collection by calling `setSelected` with a new list. There's no method to `setRecords`, though.

Comment: Thanks. I see. I wasn't sure what setselected does. The documentation doesn't say much. Would you be able to throw some light on how it works in case of pagination? Does it only set the records in the current page view?

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish? Please outline it at a high level.

Comment: I'm using a standard set controller to display some records . I have a delete button next to each object in the VF page which grabs the rowIndex and am trying to remove the record from the list returned by setCon.getRecords

Comment: So you are trying to delete listed records? Is that your end goal?

Comment: yes the end goal is to delete the records. But not instantly, it should rerender the page with the intermediate list and when the user clicks save, it should update the setCon.records collection.

Comment: Something like this : http://michaelwelburn.com/Visualforce-Edit-Multiple-Records/images/View%20-%20Editing%20Records.png

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12922/2602

Comment: @cropedy, thanks for the link. Looks similar to what I need

Comment: You can not play with setCon.getRecords();. It does not support any functions except paginations to control list. Filters are not supported. It will end up in showing all records.